# How Do Live/Boot CD Distros Run from Non-Writable Media?

Tags: livecd

How do portable Linux distributions run from non-writable media such as read-only CDs?

Where do they view the folder system as being mounted -- on the CD or on one of the hard drives of the host computer?

How do they handle the issue of necessary temp files (such as swap files)? Are these faked-out as being stored in memory, or written to a local hard drive?

I know that the Linux OS kernel anticipates a certain folder structure...so where is it?

Answer (score 0):

There are actually 3 filesystems involved:

1. A read-only compressed filesystem for the base system.
2. An inaccessible read-write tmpfs for local changes.
3. A union filesystem that binds the above two filesystems together. It reads a file from the tmpfs if it is there, and otherwise falls back to the compressed version. Writes (including deletes, which will mess with your mind if you think about it) go directly to the tmpfs.

Swap (which is not usually a file anyway) is not used (since the only writable filesystem is ram) during during an installer unless you manually mount a swap drive (which requires custom partitioning, but can help with installs on systems with less than 256 MB of RAM).

Comment: Thanks for this. But where is the inaccessible read/write tmp fs? How can it be read/write if it is inaccessible? Is the OS writing anywhere?

Comment: @PadawanLearner you do that through the unionfs. Edited.

Comment: So the unionfs consists of an underlying set of compressed/read-only files, a RAM "overlay" where changes and writes and deletes are cached, and a code "facade" for checking first the overlay and then the underlying read-only set when a file is requested? Is this unionfs compiled into the Linux kernel's main process, or is it a separate process that the kernel communicates with across process boundaries? Just wondering how easily it is switched out (the fs) when the distro is created.

One other thing...if the role of the swap file is to facilitate virtual memory with disk, how can it be RAM?